# python - use subplot with a function returning fig, ax

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am using the `ruptures.display` function inside a for loop of 4 iterations.
The function returns a `tuple[Figure, list[ndarray] | ndarray]` of Figure and Axes.

I would like to use `plt.subplot` and plot this 4 plots one above the other.
I normally use `plt.subplot(4,1, j)` but in this case I am struggling, because I do not know how to concile it with the `display` function returning matplotlib objects.

Thanks